# Default values when deserializing validated object

Tags: c#, validation, deserialization, postsharp

In a WebAPI project:

```
public class MyObject
{
   [PostSharp.Patterns.Contract.StringLength(8, 63, ErrorMessage = "blala string")]
   public string Name { get; set; }

    [PostSharp.Patterns.Contract.Range(3,5)]
    public int Num { get; set; }
}

public class MyController : ApiController
{
   public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]MyObject obj)
   {
      /// And here there's a problem...
   }
}
```

In the `Post` method, if the length of the name field that's sent is less than 8, then obj.Name will be null.
In the same manner if the num field is less than 3, then obj.Num will be 0.

This creates a problem because when just defaulting the values without throwing any exception, you get an object with fields that need to be validated again - and that kinda takes the edge off using PostSharp in this case.

BTW, I looked in the IL and and I can't find any deserialization implementations either.

So, any ideas why is this happening and what can be done?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: The validation is done in setters. Is it possible that the exception is caught by WebAPI?

Comment: Looks like you're right: through the Exceptions Menu (ctrl+alt+e in VS) I configured it to stop on exception, and I see there's a PostSharp exception that's being thrown and ignored while deserializing the request's body. I couldn't find any way to inject code or configure this behavior, and according to [this](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Global%20Error%20Handling) it might not even be possible.. Any ideas?